# why $A = 180n - B$ is NOT a solution of $\tan (A) = \tan (B)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Solving: $\tan (A) = \tan (B)$, gives: $A = 180^\circ n + B$ , where $n$ is an integer.

But why is: $A = 180^\circ n - B$, not considered to be a solution of the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use that definition for A, you get $\tan(A)=-\tan(B)$ as $\tan(x)$ is an odd function.

Comment: oh, I see, that is because $\tan (180 - B) = -\tan (B)$ , and this would lead to contradicting the original equation.

Comment: Yup, a more complete answer is that for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $180n-B=-(180(-n)+B)$, and $\tan(-x)=-\tan(x)$, so this gives $\tan(A)=\tan(-B)=-\tan(B)$ (as $-n\in\mathbb{z}$ as well)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the formula $$\tan(x+y)=\frac {\tan(x)+\tan(y)} {1-\tan(x)~\tan(y)}$$ first with $x=n\pi$ and $y=B$ and second with $x=n\pi$ and $y=-B$, you will notice the same as what Silynn wrote.

Comment: this identity clears the concept, unfortunately, trig identities are introduced after the chapter I am currently in (Trig functions) , so I was unaware of this identity. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Sorry ! You will learn it soon (as many other wonderful formulas). Cheers.